# I have an error on eigenfaces image recognition part

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, face-recognition

The error is :

> "id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]) cv2.error:
>   OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\eigen_faces.cpp:121:
>   error: (-5:Bad argument) Wrong input image size. Reason: Training and
>   Test images must be of equal size! Expected an image with 12100
>   elements, but got 25281. in function 'cv::face::Eigenfaces::predict'"

I adapt this code from LBPHFaceRecognizer then change to EigenFaceRecognizer

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 

recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX



#iniciate id counter
id = 0

# names related to ids: example ==> Marcelo: id=1,  etc
names = ['None', 'sabri', 'Naim' , 'Acap'] 

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
 cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
 cam.set(3, 640) # set video widht
 cam.set(4, 480) # set video height

# Define min window size to be recognized as a face
minW = 0.1*cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(4)

while True:

ret, img =cam.read()
img = cv2.flip(img, 1) # Flip vertically

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
    gray,
    scaleFactor = 1.2,
    minNeighbors = 5,
    minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
   )

for(x,y,w,h) in faces:

    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

    id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

    # Check if confidence is less them 100 ==> "0" is perfect match 
    if (confidence < 100):
        id = names[id]
        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
    else:
        id = "unknown"
        confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))

    cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  

cv2.imshow('camera',img) 

k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
if k == 27:
    break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the size of your training image is different than your testing image. In your code, you have set the input as 480*640 and you have not resized it before you feed to the prediction model. If your training size is 480*640 your testing size should be 480*640. You can use `cv2.resize()` to resize your testing image or your training image or both.

Comment: i already put in my training code, but where i should put cv2.resize() in testing code?

Comment: I think the problem is that in your program run your width is 480 and in training it is 640. Also, edit your question to further explain what you did rather than answering it. Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

This my code training

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'

recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):

    height_d, width_d = 480, 640  # Declare your own width and height

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

    PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
    img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

    id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        faceSamples.append(cv2.resize(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w], (height_d, width_d )))
        ids.append(id)

return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```